# Getting root ViewGroup in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to implement a custom dialog in a PreferenceActivity that still has the Android-generic positive/neutral/negative buttons in the dialog, i.e. a custom AlertDialog. The way to go seems to be described in the bottom example of this article: [Dialogs on Android developer pages](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) .

However, I can't find a way to get the root for a PreferenceActivity for doing this:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.??????));
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get rootview of any view

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
View view = layout.getRootView();
```